# Много вопросов у новичка (Java)

Tags: java

Здравствуйте. Начал изучать Java. Вот собственно код одной из первых написанных программ (описание программы и вопросы даны после кода):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class ReadAndParse {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        double a, b, c;
        double D;
        double x1, x2;

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        System.out.print("A=");
        String s1 = br.readLine();

        System.out.print("B=");
        String s2 = br.readLine();

        System.out.print("C=");
        String s3 = br.readLine();

        a = Double.parseDouble(s1);
        b = Double.parseDouble(s2);
        c = Double.parseDouble(s3);

        D = b * b - 4 * a * c;
        x1 = (-b - Math.sqrt(D)) / (2 * a);
        x2 = (-b + Math.sqrt(D)) / (2 * a);

        System.out.println("x1=" + Double.toString(x1));
        System.out.println("x1=" + x2);
    }
}
```

Программа считает корни квадратного уравнения. Все работает хорошо, но делал по книжке, поэтому остались некоторые непонятные моменты.

1. `void` значит "пустота", "пустой" это значит что функция, в данном случае main не возвращает значение после конца выполнения" - прочитал я в интернете, но не очень понял, что к чему, хотел бы увидеть пример/сравнение с функцией, которая возвращает значение.
2. Не до конца разобрался со строчкой вызова `BufferedReader`, для чего пишется "new" и для чего нужен текст в скобках `(new InputStreamReader(System.in));`
3. Почему(и для чего, ведь число уже отпарсено в коде раннее) в первом случае мы пишем `Double.toString(x1)`, а во втором - нет?

   ```
   System.out.println("x1=" + Double.toString(x1));   
   System.out.println("x2=" + x2);
   ```
4. Сложно ли найти работу Java-программисту? Какие затраты по времени, примерно, могут ожидать, чтобы найти первую, пусть и не крутую, но работу. (Если учитывать, что высшего образования нет, я вот только-только закончил школу, и даже не знаю, поступлю ли в ВУЗ).
5. Какую литературу посоветуете по Java?

Comment: Разбейте "много вопросов" на отдельные, более конкретные, вопросы.

Comment: все что вы тут спросили - элементарнейшие основы основ, которые изложены абсолютно в любой книге по Java. Прежде чем переписывать какие то программы, не понимая, что и зачем пишешь, я бы вам рекомендовал сначала завести хоть какую-то теоретическую базу. Нет вообще никакого смысла писать код, не понимая, что написал, а потом спрашивать - что это такое было. Читать можно книги Эккеля, Шилдта - признаные авторитеты Java.

Comment: Чтобы стать востребованным программистом, нужно поменьше спрашивать, ожидая, когда кто то за вас решит проблему и самому читать, учиться - много, долго, упорно, решать задачи, появившиеся проблемы самому. Что такое new? - открыл документацию, учебники - вник сам во все нюансы, что когда зачем почему. Никому в команде, в общем то, не нужен груз, который только спрашивает, не демонстрирует желания саморазвиваться, решать вопросы без посторонней помощи. Думаете высокие зарплаты программистам за "длинный язык" платят. С таким, как у вас подходом, расчитывать на что то кроме эникейщика не стоит.

Comment: Надеюсь вы сделаете правильные выводы из моей писанины.

Comment: Затраты по времени будут очень разные в каждом индивидуальном случае и говорить о каких то попытках устроится на работу можно будет тогда, когда ваш ник будет чаще напротив слов - "ответ дан" с зеленой галочкой слева, а не "задан".

Comment: Я бы порекомендовал книжку "Изучаем Java" от Кэти Сьерра (как это делают в ответе). Там всё очень грамотно написано, как раз разбирают все темы Вашего вопроса. Причём хочу так же отметить, что книжка расчитана как раз на новичка

Answer (score 1):

1)  Функция может возвращать любой тип данных, существующий в Java, или объект класса, созданного вами:

```
public static String myMethod() { 
    String s = "Hello!";
    return s;
}
```

Тогда, при вызове в коде, вы сможете присваивать возвращаемые методом значения переменным, имеющим тип, совпадающий с возвращаемым методом, либо наследуемым от него:

```
String st = myMethod();
```

Или же:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    MyClass a = new MyClass();
    MyClass b;
    b = a;
}

class MyClass {
    MyClass() {}
}
```

2) Ключевое слово `new` означает создание экземпляра класса, таким образом вы вызываете конструктор.

3) Изначально вы вводите строку `String s1 = br.readLine()`, а значит, оперировать с ней, как с double, у вас не получится, для этого нужно привести её к типу double, ибо в строке может содержаться что угодно. 
Переменную x2 вы изначально объявляете как double, а при инициализации присваиваете ей также double значение.

4) Этот вопрос может касаться не только работы Java-программистом, а вообще любой работы, и является слишком общим.

5) Этот вопрос тоже является слишком общим. Вот первый же ответ из поиска в google: https://habrahabr.ru/post/153373/. Но всё же, от себя **Head First Java** от O'Reilly Media, чтобы понять основы, вам будет более чем достаточно.

Насчёт первых трёх вопросов: вся эта информация общедоступна, находится очень легко и быстро в интернете. Найдите нормальное руководство, хорошую книжку, туториал, читайте документацию. Заданные вами вопросы слишком элементарны, и если бы каждый задавал, не стараясь найти эту информацию сам, было бы не очень хорошо.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. void значит "пустота", "пустой" это значит что функция, в данном случае main не возвращает значение после конца выполнения" - прочитал я в интернете, но не очень понял, что к чему, хотел бы увидеть пример/сравнение с функцией, которая возвращает значение.

В Java, законченную последовательность действий, направленных на решение некоторой задачи, принято называть *методом*, а не *функцией*, как, например, в C++.

Пример метода, который имеет возвращаемое значение:

```
private static int inc(int value) {
    return ++value;
}
```

Где-то в коде Вы можете вызвать этот метод и получить из него значение:

```
int incValue = inc(1);
```

> 2. Не до конца разобрался со строчкой вызова `BufferedReader`, для чего пишется "new" и для чего нужен текст в скобках `(new InputStreamReader(System.in));`

Оператор `new` используется для создание объекта. Здесь создается объект класса `InputStreamReader` с помощью конструктора, куда передается объект `System.in`.

> 3. Почему(и для чего, ведь число уже отпарсено в коде раннее) в первом случае мы пишем  Double.toString(x1), а во втором - нет?
>
>    System.out.println("x1=" + Double.toString(x1));
>    System.out.println("x2=" + x2);

В данном случае, явная конвертация `Double -> String` не нужна, так как она происходит неявно.

> 4. Сложно ли найти работу Java-программисту? Какие затраты по времени, примерно, могут ожидать, чтобы найти первую, пусть и не крутую, но работу. (Если учитывать, что высшего образования нет, я вот только-только закончил школу, и даже не знаю, поступлю ли в ВУЗ).

Хорошему – не сложно. Все очень индивидуально. Можно ориентироваться на год.

> 5. Какую литературу посоветуете по Java?

Классика: Шилдт, Эккель, Хорстманн. И ни в коем случае не следует изучать *фундаментальные* вещи по статьям из интернета и видеоурокам.

А, кстати, лично мне, серия Head First не нравится.

Comment: Ну на самом деле на счёт Head First всё очень индивидуально. Но как знаю по своему опыту и по рассказам знакомых, это книга очень хороша конкретно для старта)

Comment: @SlandShow, Я это не отрицаю.